# Mockserver cannot connect to any port

Tags: java, spring, api, port, mockserver

Im using a mockserver to test api requests.

The mockserver wont start.

This is my code

```
@SpringBootTest
class RestApiMetaDataApplicationTests {
    private ClientAndServer mockServer;

    @BeforeClass
    public void startServer() throws Exception {
        mockServer = startClientAndServer(1080);
    }
 
    @AfterClass 
    public void stopServer() { 
        mockServer.stop();
        
    }
    
  
    @Test
    public void shouldReturnTrack() throws Exception {
        String isrc = "TEST1234560000";
        String responseBody = "{\"id\": \"1234\",\"name\": \"Some new track!\",\"duration_ms\": 12000000}";

        new MockServerClient("localhost", 1080)
            .when(
                request()
                    .withMethod("GET")
                    .withPath("/codechallenge/createTrack/" + isrc)
            )
            .respond(
            response()
                .withStatusCode(200)
                .withBody(responseBody)
                .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        );

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .GET()
        .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:1080/codechallenge/createTrack/" + isrc))
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .build();
    HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = httpClient.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    String response = httpResponse.body();

    assertEquals(responseBody, response);
    assertEquals(200, httpResponse.statusCode());
}}
```

There is nothing running on port 1080 and I have tried other ports and none of them work.

I have found this thread on Github of other people encountering the same issue but none of the solutions offered have worked for me

[link to github](https://github.com/mock-server/mockserver/issues/498https://)

The dependencies I am using are

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockserver-netty</artifactId>
        <version>5.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockserver-client-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.11.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This is some of the stacktrace

```
org.mockserver.client.SocketConnectionException: Unable to connect to socket localhost/127.0.0.1:1080
at org.mockserver.client.NettyHttpClient.sendRequest(NettyHttpClient.java:180)
at org.mockserver.client.MockServerClient.sendRequest(MockServerClient.java:211)
at org.mockserver.client.MockServerClient.sendRequest(MockServerClient.java:244)
at org.mockserver.client.MockServerClient.upsert(MockServerClient.java:1109)
at org.mockserver.client.ForwardChainExpectation.respond(ForwardChainExpectation.java:50)
at net.codejava.song.RestApiMetaDataApplicationTests.shouldReturnTrack(RestApiMetaDataApplicationTests.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
at
```

added plugin import for mockserver

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockserver-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <serverPort>1080</serverPort>
                <proxyPort>1090</proxyPort>
                <logLevel>DEBUG</logLevel>
                <initializationClass>org.mockserver.maven.ExampleInitializationClass</initializationClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process-test-classes</id>
                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>verify</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: can you show your plugin import for mock server? and its configurations?

Comment: @MohammedFataka added now

Comment: add how do you run mockServer? what is the command do you use for testing ? e.g `mvn mockserver:run` is command to run mock server! are you using it?

Comment: I dont run a command, I just run the junit test, that builds and runs the spring project and runs the junit and immedity fails because it cant connect

Answer (score 0):

the reason it is failing is you do not start the mock server and upon test, it will fail because there is nothing started at that port, I'm assuming you want it to automatically start server before the test, thus there are two options:

first: configure test task to be dependent of `moctserver:run` task
second: when running test task before running a test task run a mock server.

check [official docs](https://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/running_mock_server.html) for more info